# I want to Automatically Generate Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a large SQL Server database and I want to automatically generate ASP.NET and AJAX code from the database.

Can I do it using any Free Tool (please tell free ones only)?

I also want that tool to generate C# code only. Any article/whitepaper on the tool is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want the generated code to do? Like listing the SQL database contents?

Comment: You can also check out Dynamic DataWebSite..search in googl

Comment: Are you trying to avoid programming all together?

Comment: Mitch - Itried google but it shows many tools
Spoike -  Iwant to create CRUD pages of the tables
ccook - If possible yes.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Text Template Transformation Toolkit (T4)?

[This post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) has a lot of information on it.

Comment: Does T4 come with ASP.NET templates?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx)?

@Viks's suggestion of ASP.NET Dynamic Data is a good one, though you should check if it is ready for production releases:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/14/new-asp-net-dynamic-data-support.aspx

http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/

http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Dynamic%20Data&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0):

I propose using classes from: **System.CodeDom** namespace, combined with: System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider class.
For a comprehensive tutorial please see: [Microsoft .NET CodeDom Technology - Part 1
By Brian J. Korzeniowski](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020917.htm)